# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - [object Object ] dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react

Tags: reactjs, object, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

The following snippet throws the `Object object` error

```
<script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: new PermutiveScriptLoader({
              cluster: CLUSTER,
              projectId: PERMUTIVE_PROJECT_ID_BF_US,
              apiKey: PERMUTIVE_API_KEY_BF_US,
            }),
          }}
          key="permutive-script"
        />
```

I thought it is because the dangerouslySetInnerHTML expects to return a string and therefore tried to stringify. But the below snippet throws the below error

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

```
<script>{"projectId":"6ef7b2c1-fe43-45ad-8551-5377c13e2f71","apiKey":"e275d97e-aa77-43e0-ac22-71c7d5d5ad5a","cluster":"dev"}</script>`



<script
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: JSON.stringify(new PermutiveScriptLoader({
              cluster: CLUSTER,
              projectId: PERMUTIVE_PROJECT_ID_BF_US,
              apiKey: PERMUTIVE_API_KEY_BF_US,
            })),
          }}
          key="permutive-script"
        />
```

Comment: What is `PermutiveScriptLoader`, and what are you expecting this code to do?  `[object Object]` isn't an *error*, it's the default string representation of an object which otherwise has no useful `toString` implementation.  So this object you're using has no default string representation.  Then you are successfully serializing the object to JSON... but why?  You're successfully outputting a JavaScript object literal, by itself, which does exactly nothing.  (And produces an error because the language doesn't expect that.)  What is the actual goal here?

Comment: export class PermutiveScriptLoader {
  constructor({ cluster, projectId, apiKey }) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.cluster = cluster;

    this._loadPermutiveScript();
  }

loadPermutiveScript() -> loads the script in the DOM like this.. <script src="https://cdn.permutive.com/f123-sbhds-767-web.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I am expecting this code to load the script in the DOM like this <script src="https://cdn.permutive.com/1234-web.js" async="" type="text/javascript"></script>

But I see the DOM like this now
<script>[object Object]</script>

Comment: Relevant code belongs in the question, not in comments where it's barely readable.  Is this some 3rd party tool you're using?  Does that tool provide documentation for how to use it?  What is that `loadPermutiveScript()` function being called in the class?  Does *that* function output a `<script>` element to the page?  If so, why are you also trying to output the object *itself* to the page?  It looks like you need to check back with the documentation/support for this tool you're using, because the attempt you're showing makes very, very little sense.

Comment: Sorry about the unclear explanation. I will try to explain it better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408998/scriptobject-promise-script-returned-instead-of-stringified-snippet-of-js I created a new question